# Как реализовать поиск по txt файлу? VK API PHP

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Суть проблемы/идеи такова.

Каждый час документ будет проверятся на наличие там записей возможных для удаления...

Например: Сейчас 12:00, он находит в документе все значения возле которых аналогичное время и удаляет их, а после и из документа.

---

В документе значения сохраняются в таком виде:

> wall-177279513-595 | 12:00
>   wall-177279513-597 | 12:00
>   wall-177279513-605 | 14:00

`Запись | Время удаления данной записи`

---

Пытался реализовать с помощью чтения из документа значений и его перебора через `foreach` но потерпел "фиаско"...

PS. Сам код

```
class wall_delete{
    public function send($post_id, $group_id, $standalone_token){
        $request_params = array(
            "owner_id" => $group_id,
            "post_id" => $post_id,
            "access_token" => $standalone_token,
            "v" => "5.92");
        $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
        file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.delete?".$get_params);}}


            $str = explode("\n", file_get_contents(__DIR__."/reposts.txt"));
            foreach($str as $value){
                $str_2 = explode(" | ", $value);
                if("12:00" == $str_2[1]){
                    $wd->send($str_2[0], "177279513", $standalone_token);
                }}
```

Реализовать поиск получилось, но заставить его удалять запись через [Метод удаления записей](https://vk.com/dev/wall.delete) ВК не получается...

Comment: приложите ваш код к вопросу

Comment: @ArchDemon, добавил